# Are there sufficient conditions to show that $⊗0=0$ in this incomplete defintion of a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is from the first paragraph of Hermann Weyl's *The Classical Groups*. (Facsimile included below.)  At some time in the past I probably convinced myself that the assertion is true based on the given definitions.  But I didn't keep good notes, and may well have been in error.

I do not believe Weyl expects us to draw from the definition of *field*, since that is what he is developing.

## Defintions:

We have a set with two binary operations $\left\langle S,\oplus,\otimes\right\rangle $
which is closed, associative and commutative under $\oplus$

\begin{align*}
\alpha\oplus\beta\in & S,\\
\left(\alpha\oplus\beta\right)\oplus\gamma= & \alpha\oplus\left(\beta\oplus\gamma\right),\\
\alpha\oplus\beta= & \beta\oplus\alpha;
\end{align*}

closed, associative and commutative under $\otimes$

\begin{align*}
\alpha\otimes\beta\in & S,\\
\left(\alpha\otimes\beta\right)\otimes\gamma= & \alpha\otimes\left(\beta\otimes\gamma\right),\\
\alpha\otimes\beta= & \beta\otimes\alpha;
\end{align*}

$\oplus$ has a unique inversion, and $\otimes$ distributes over
$\oplus$
\begin{align*}
\exists0\in & S\backepsilon\alpha\oplus0=\alpha,\\
\forall\alpha\exists-\alpha\in & S\backepsilon\alpha\oplus\left(-\alpha\right)=0.\\
\alpha\oplus\beta=0\implies & \beta=-\alpha,\\
\alpha\otimes\left(\beta\oplus\gamma\right)= & \left(\alpha\otimes\beta\right)\oplus\left(\alpha\otimes\gamma\right).
\end{align*}

#### The implication to be demonstrated:

From this it follows that 
$$
\alpha\otimes0=0.
$$

## Comments and question:

With the understanding that the definitions are restricted to those given above we may replace

\begin{align*}
\alpha\oplus\beta\mapsto & \alpha+\beta,\\
\alpha\otimes\beta\mapsto & \alpha\beta.
\end{align*}

Clearly for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we have $\alpha\left(\beta+\left(-\beta\right)\right)=\alpha0.$
But we have not been given a multiplicative inverse, nor even a unit element. We also haven't been formally told the order of the set.

### Based on the definitions given above, can Weyl's assertion be demonstrated?

#### This is how the development appears in the book:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I see the question here.  You are correct that the discussion you wrote does not establish the existence of a multiplicative identity. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: If you are just asking whether we can deduce that $a\otimes 0=0$ then, sure.  After all $a\otimes 0=a\otimes (0\oplus 0)=(a\otimes 0) \oplus (a\otimes 0)$ and now we can "subtract" $a\otimes 0$ from both sides to get the desired result.  Though, again, I am not sure that this is what you are asking.

Comment: Note that none of what I wrote pertains to zero-divisors (which you reference in your header, but not elsewhere).  One might, say, look at the ring of matrices over a field, wherein it is perfectly true that $M\times 0=0$ for all $M$  but alas $M\times N=0$ does not imply that at least one of $M,N$ is itself $0$.

Comment: After I posted, I realized that this probably isn't about divisors of zero.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton With the given axioms, you can prove that if $x\oplus x=x$, then $x=0$, because you have $x\oplus(-x)=(x\oplus x)\oplus(-x)=x\oplus(x\oplus(-x))$ and therefore $0=x\oplus0=x$. Now apply it to $\alpha\otimes0=\alpha\otimes(0\oplus0)=\alpha\otimes0\oplus\alpha\otimes0$ with $x=\alpha\otimes0$. What you *cannot* prove is that if $\alpha\otimes\beta=0$, then either $\alpha=0$ or $\beta=0$ (because there are rings where this isn't true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $0 + 0 = 0$.

By distributivity,
$0\alpha = (0 + 0)\alpha = 0\alpha + 0\alpha$.

Adding $−0\alpha$ (Inverse of $0\alpha$) on both sides gives $0 = 0\alpha$. Similarly, $0=\alpha 0$.